# Table width exceeds container's width

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm working on a reporting application which generates HTML tables that can be many rows high and many columns long (sometimes 40 or more).

The problem is, many of these tables stretch outside of their containing div, and it just looks ugly. For some reason, the containing div won't stretch to the size of the table.

So, here's my question: Is it possible to make a containing element stretch to the width of the table using CSS?

Here's a [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qn5KH/1/) with the problem at its most basic level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give your container a float to force it to stretch to the width of the content:

```
div{
    border:2px solid #F00;
    padding:10px;   
    float: left; 
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qn5KH/3/)

Comment: While I don't understand why floating should fix a problem like this, it seems like that did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

just put `<div style="overfow:auto"><table>` and happy coding

```css
div{
    border:2px solid #F00;
    padding:10px;    
}
table{
    border:2px solid #00F;    
}
td, th{
    border:1px solid #00F;
    padding:4px;    
}
```

```html
<div style="overflow: auto">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Lorem</th>
            <th>Ipsum</th>
            <th>Dolor</th>
            <th>Sit</th>
            <th>Amet</th>
            <th>Lorem</th>
            <th>Ipsum</th>
            <th>Dolor</th>
            <th>Sit</th>
            <th>Amet</th>
            <th>Lorem</th>
            <th>Ipsum</th>
            <th>Dolor</th>
            <th>Sit</th>
            <th>Amet</th>
            <th>Lorem</th>
            <th>Ipsum</th>
            <th>Dolor</th>
            <th>Sit</th>
            <th>Amet</th>
            <th>Lorem</th>
            <th>Ipsum</th>
            <th>Dolor</th>
            <th>Sit</th>
            <th>Amet</th>
            <th>Lorem</th>
            <th>Ipsum</th>
            <th>Dolor</th>
            <th>Sit</th>
            <th>Amet</th>
            <th>Lorem</th>
            <th>Ipsum</th>
            <th>Dolor</th>
            <th>Sit</th>
            <th>Amet</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Lorem</td>
            <td>Ipsum</td>
            <td>Dolor</td>
            <td>Sit</td>
            <td>Amet</td>
            <td>Lorem</td>
            <td>Ipsum</td>
            <td>Dolor</td>
            <td>Sit</td>
            <td>Amet</td>
            <td>Lorem</td>
            <td>Ipsum</td>
            <td>Dolor</td>
            <td>Sit</td>
            <td>Amet</td>
            <td>Lorem</td>
            <td>Ipsum</td>
            <td>Dolor</td>
            <td>Sit</td>
            <td>Amet</td>
            <td>Lorem</td>
            <td>Ipsum</td>
            <td>Dolor</td>
            <td>Sit</td>
            <td>Amet</td>
            <td>Lorem</td>
            <td>Ipsum</td>
            <td>Dolor</td>
            <td>Sit</td>
            <td>Amet</td>
            <td>Lorem</td>
            <td>Ipsum</td>
            <td>Dolor</td>
            <td>Sit</td>
            <td>Amet</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider about another method -- Set table-layout as fixed in your table class:

```
table-layout:auto;
```

Idea from another [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17969877/force-html-tables-to-not-exceed-their-containers-size)